# Get the index of smallest non-negative number in an array?

Tags: perl

I have an array which looks like this

```
@array = ('3', '4', '71', '1', '-598', '-100203');
```

I want to find the index of the smallest non-negative number among the integers in the array.

For this case:

- smallest non-negative number = 1
- index of smallest non-negative number = 3

Comment: Thank you for your reply @MdJohirulIslam. I am not looking for the smallest number, but the smallest whole number. Whole numbers includes 0 and all positive numbers only.

Comment: "Whole number" appears to mean different things to different people. (To many including myself and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Awhole+number), it means a number without a fractional component, which includes -5.) Fixed the question to use unambiguous language.

Comment: [Crossposted to PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1217669).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to `reduce` (O(N)), not `sort` (O(N log N))!

```
use List::Util qw( reduce );

my $i =
   reduce { $array[$a] <= $array[$b] ? $a : $b }
      grep { $array[$_] >= 0 }
         0..$#array;
```

---

If you want optimal performance, the following will get you closer:

```
use Config     qw( %Config );
use List::Util qw( minstr );

my $i =
   unpack "x$Config{ivsize} J",
      minstr
         map { pack 'J> J', $array[$_], $_ }
            grep { $array[$_] >= 0 }
               0..$#array;
```

Comment: The OP is looking for the *smallest non-negative number* in the list, not the number with the smallest magnitude.

Comment: Adjusted for clarified question

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to sort a list of index numbers, then pick the first one:

```
my $ix = (sort { $array[$a]) <=> $array[$b] } grep { $array[$_] >= 0 } 0..$#array)[0];
```

Comment: Needlessly expensive!

Comment: And `my $ix = (...)[0];` is probably more clearly written as `my ($ix) = ...;`

Comment: It is unnecessary to `sort` the list. You don't care that *all* of the values are in order, only that the smallest whole number comes first.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way is to scan the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# always use these two
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw( :all );

# --------------------------------------
#       Name: smallest_whole_number
#      Usage: ( $smallest, $index ) = smallest_whole_number( @array );
#    Purpose: Find the smallest whole number in an array.
# Parameters: @array -- array of integers
#    Returns: ( $smallest, $index ) unless exception.
#             ( -1, -1 ) if exception.
#
sub smallest_whole_number {
    my @array = @_;

    # check if array empty
    return ( -1, -1 ) unless @array;

    # scan for first whole number
    my $index = 0;
    while( $array[$index] < 0 ){

        # exception if no whole numbers in array
        return ( -1, -1 ) if $index >= $#array;

        $index ++;
    }

    # save first whole number found
    my $smallest = $array[$index];

    # scan the rest of the array
    for( my $i = $index + 1; $i <= $#array; $i ++ ){
        my $nbr = $array[$i];

        # skip negative numbers
        next if $nbr < 0;

        # check if current number smaller
        if( $smallest > $nbr ){
            $smallest = $nbr;
            $index    = $i;
        }
    }

    return ( $smallest, $index );
}

# --------------------------------------
# main

my @array = ('3', '4', '71', '1', '-598', '-100203');

my ( $smallest, $index ) = smallest_whole_number( @array );
say "smallest is $smallest at index $index";
```

Comment: Re "*In Perl, indexing starts at zero, so the index is 2 (not 3).*", No, the answer is correctly 3. 0:3, 1:4, 2:71, 3:1, 4:-598, 5:-100203